# simple preg_replace replacing anchor text

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Having issues wish a preg_replace function.

I am formatting a breadcrumb which the php is ioncubed so I am having to preg_replace to remove part of the breadcrumb.

I have a breadcrumb that looks like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="mylink1.html">Link 1</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="mylink2.html">Link 2</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
    <li><a href="mylink3.html">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is completely remove

```
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
```

My Original thoughts were to just str_replace

```
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></li>
```

with nothing however the link can vary depending on the language file loaded.

I then thought about preg_replace the content of the url as the href is constant however I have absolutley no experiance with PHP and all attempts I have tried give random responses.

I'm hoping someone can help with the preg_replace or even if there is a better way to remove the line.

So far Ive tried

```
$str = '<li><a href="mylink.php">Link 2</a></li>';

$preg_replace = preg_replace('<li><a href="mylink.php">(.*)','placeholder',$str);

echo $preg_replace;
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your most promising attempts

Comment: [THE PONY HE COMES...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bound your regex, typically with `/`. You also might want to include the closing tag or your regex will match more than you want

```
$preg_replace = preg_replace('/<li><a href="mylink\.php">(.*)<\/a>/','placeholder',$str);
```

I highly recommend http://regex101.com/ for learning more about regex and how to make them work.

Comment: regex101 says: `unescaped delimiter`: period and slashes

Comment: Nice stuff. I thought he wanted something simpler

Comment: However, when you work with html, `/` is a bad choice as delimiter since you must escape all the slashes in the pattern.